# Placing elements into the UITableView footer, when to release them?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    AViewController * aView = [[AViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];    
    return vintagePriceRowView.view;
}
```

I know this code needs a release... somewhere. But where? If I set the allocated AviewController to autorelease, then touching elements within the view results in a "message sent to deallocated instance 0xfb5780"

The Leaks instrument is not actually showing a leak, but obviously Clang does not like the above code. I know Clang is not the gospel as far as determining everything that could possibly be wrong in your code, but in this case, it *feels* like it is probably right. I've allocated it, I need to release it.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency's sake, you should create the view that you'll be using in the footer before it's required. Maybe create it in viewDidLoad in your tableViewController and store it in a member variable.

Then in your viewForFooter method simply return the view you stored earlier.

Then in your tableViewController's dealloc method, release the view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold on to it until it is not longer needed.

I suggest making a private property, set it to `nil` initially, and then lazy load the nib and assign the returned view to the property. Then in `dealloc` or in `viewDidUnload` simply set it to `nil` via the setter.

You will of course need to `release` or `autorelease` once you assigned it to the private property, since the setter will retain it for you.